# Random order of a HashSet is always same until Server stopped

Tags: java, hashset

`HashSet` does not maintain the order of its elements.I deployed my app to `jBoss` server and I was observing the order of a `HashSet`.
**It was random.**

But always had that same random order *until I restarted my Application server*.
Anyone can explain this situation with underlying mechanisms?

I was digging into a issue which related to Order of the elements of a `HashSet<Object>`.

Some of our servers had correct order always maintaining (still it's random) and some didn't. After I have done restarts, I figured this out.

Comment: The answer would depend on the type of elements you store in the HashSet and the hashCode implementation of their class.

Comment: The order is not random, it's entirely deterministic.  However, it's unpredictable unless you know the internal code of HashSet.

Comment: It's HashSet<Object>

Comment: Do you overwrite hashCode and equal methods for your objects? Or are you using java Objects from java.util.*?

Comment: I haven't override any methods. I was just using the default implementations. What is was storing was; Objects = POJO

Comment: Why do you care? There's nothing in the Javadoc that says it will ever be the same, or ever different for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HashSet` does not guarantee the order of the elements in it, but this does not mean the order will randomly change. The order of elements will only change when the hashes need to be re-computed, and this only happens when the capacity of the underlying hash table needs to change.

The specifics of when the capacity of the Hash changes may vary between different implementations, but it is guaranteed that if the number of the elements in the HashSet divided by the capacity of the HashSet exceeds its `loadFactor`, the HashSet's capacity will increase. Whenever the capacity increases, the hash code of all elements is re-computed and thus the order of the elements may change.

Comment: Great!. Appreciate if you can elaborate more for future readers.

Comment: What do you mean by "elaborate more" which part of your question is unclear?

Comment: underlying mechanisms?

Comment: I've added one more paragraph - hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

As you said you did not override `hashcode` method, you are using the default from `Object` class. The javadoc says : *As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)*

That means that (assuming you are using an Oracle JVM, or a similar one), the hashcode of your objects will simply be their memory address. This is fixed for a program run, but they will certainly be different for different runs, depending where the program is loaded. As the hash function is **not** monotonic, the order in the HashSet will be different (but always deterministic as said by  Oliver Charlesworth .

Comment: The hash code has not been the memory address for a long time.